# How to create an animated WebP using WebPShop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, animation, web-standards, webp

In the [README](https://github.com/webmproject/WebPShop/blob/main/README.md) for **WebPShop** (a Photoshop plugin for saving WebP files) there is mention of a method for creating ***animated* WebP files**, but the method for producing such files is not described in detail. The only information given is as follows:

> The Timeline data is not used; thus animations rely on layers for
> defining frames (set duration as "(123 ms)" in each layer's name), and
> they need to be rasterized before saving.

I labeled the layers with the naming convention described above, and chose **File** > **Save a Copy...**

Unfortunately, it only produced a regular (unanimated) WebP file.

What other steps are required to get Photoshop to output an *animated* **.webp** file using the WebPShop plugin? Thanks.

<sub>Version used: **Photoshop 2024** 25.1.0 Release</sub>